how was this patent granted after a final rejection?
https://patentcenter.uspto.gov/applications/17861962/ifw/docs?application=
https://patents.google.com/patent/US12019694B1/en?oq=US11386172B1
The above patent is a continuation of:
https://patents.google.com/patent/US11386172B1/en?oq=US11386172B1

In the patent center, the continued application was issued a Final Rejection. But it is granted anyways.
Furthermore, the claims of the granted continued application are different from those in the transaction records.
Can someone explain the above inconsistencies?

The file wrapper you linked shows an RCE following the "final" rejection. An RCE is one valid option for continuing prosecution of the application following a final rejection. "Final" just means the applicant can't amend further without paying additional fees.

Final rejections are not really final. Strange but true.

@bhuff36 what about the inconsistency in the claims that were granted versus those in the transaction records?

@EricS what about the inconsistency in the claims that were granted versus those in the transaction records?

I have neither the time nor interest in analyzing patent prosecutions. Sorry.

_Bear: Have you checked against the CLM amended 01/08/2024?

@bhuff36 Yes, in that document, it uses the term "collection". In the final granted patent, the term "range" is used instead. So it doesn't explain the discrepancy.
